# Find max element between two vectors

Tags: c++

I thought the following would work but it just outputs zero. Ideas?

```
std::vector<int> a = { 1, 2, 3 };
std::vector<int> b = { 4, 5, 6 };

int max = *std::max(std::max(a.begin(), a.end()), std::max(b.begin(), b.end()));
std::cout << max;
```

Comment: Please read the documentation for `std::max`. It doesn't take ranges.

Comment: Take a look at [`std::max_element`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max_element) instead.

Comment: @Joseph Great resource!

Comment: @user4194178 I still consider cppreference one of the most important things I learned on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're using [`std::max`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max), which compares its arguments. That is, it's returning the greater of the two iterators.

What you want for the inner invocation is [`std::max_element`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max_element), which finds the maximum element in a range:

```
std::vector<int> a = { 1, 2, 3 };
std::vector<int> b = { 4, 5, 6 };

int max = std::max(*std::max_element(a.begin(), a.end()), *std::max_element(b.begin(), b.end()));
std::cout << max;
```

<kbd>[Live example](http://ideone.com/g1yNJT)</kbd>

As @MikeSeymour correctly pointed out in comments, the above code assumes the ranges are not empty, as it unconditionally dereferences the iterators returned from `std::max_element`. If one of the ranges was empty, the returned iterator would be the past-the-end one, which cannot be dereferenced.

Comment: While it's not a problem in this example, you need to make sure the range is non-empty before dereferencing the iterator.

Comment: @MikeSeymour Right, mentioned.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a way that behaves sensibly with empty ranges.  If either range is empty, you still get the maximum from the other range.  If both ranges are empty, you get `INT_MIN`.

```cpp
auto op = [](int a, int b) { return std::max(a, b); }; // 1)
int m = std::reduce(begin(b), end(b),
        std::reduce(begin(a), end(a), INT_MIN, op), op);
```

[`std::reduce`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/reduce)<sup>2)</sup> is better here, since you want a value, not an iterator as the result.

---

<sup>1)</sup> we need a lambda wrapper [because we are not allowed to](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55687045/5740428) take the address of `std::max`
<sup>2)</sup> pre-C++-17, you can use `std::accumulate`

Answer (score 0):

```
int m = std::max(std::max_element(a.begin(), a.end()), std::max_element(b.begin(), b.end()));
```

This finds maximum of the maximums of the individual vectors. For example, for 1st vector, { 1, 2, 3 }, max value is 3, and for 2nd vector, { 4, 5, 6 }, max value is 6, max of 3 and 6 is now 6