# C++ type deduction of overloaded function

Tags: c++, gcc, clang, language-lawyer

Is this legal code?

```
#include <utility>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    const auto func2 = std::swap<int>;
}
```

This code seems legal to me. But the compilers don't agree with each other. GCC is happy with it, but clang gives an error.

```
prog.cc:8:16: error: variable 'func2' with type 'const auto' has incompatible initializer of type '<overloaded function type>'
const auto func2 = std::swap<int>;
           ^       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

So, I'm confused. Can anyone explain?

I'm using clang 9.0.0 on [wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/9LSKZtp4rNH5zuAS):

```
clang++ prog.cc -Wall -Wextra -I/opt/wandbox/boost-1.70.0/clang-6.0.1/include -std=c++17
```

Comment: I believe it's undefined behavior to take the address of a standard function.

Comment: @0x499602D2 but why the compiler is not happy with that??

Comment: Is that the entire error message? Often the compiler follows the error message with some notes that give more details.

Comment: @PeteBecker. Now it has the entire error message.

Comment: @0x499602D2 It is "unspecified (possibly ill-formed)", except for some I/O manipulators.

Comment: This seems to be an issue with the latest clang and `<iostream>`.

Comment: Okay; the compiler really isn’t helping here.

Comment: [Can I take the address of a function defined in standard library?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55687044/995714)

Comment: Note there is more than one `swap` overload.  In particular, we have the array overload.

Comment: Per phuclv, possible duplicate of [Can I take the address of a function defined in standard library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55687044/can-i-take-the-address-of-a-function-defined-in-standard-library)

Comment: The funny thing is, that it happily compiles with clang-HEAD (or 8/7/6) on godbolt: https://godbolt.org/z/3spfoa.