# Why can't I get the address of std::swap with auto?

Tags: c++, c++17

I had the following line in some C++ code inside of a template function:

```
auto swapper = std::swap<T>;
```

And when compiling, using `T=int`, for instance, I get the following compiler error:

```
error: unable to deduce ‘auto’ from ‘swap<int>’
|  auto swapper = std::swap<T>;
|       ^~~~~~~
note:   couldn’t deduce template parameter ‘auto’
```

If I explicitly declare the type for `swapper` it works:

```
void (*swapper)(T&,T&) = std::swap<T>;
```

However, I am still puzzled as to why I can't declare `swapper` as `auto`?

Comment: There are multiple overloads of `std::swap`. Unless you provide the type, the compiler can't know which of them you wish to take an address of.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik From what I can see there is only one possible overload once template arguments are known, and here they are explicitly provided. Interestingly, [clang compiles this just fine](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9a0b51dbed39cbde) -- GCC does seem to choke, and I don't know why.

Comment: @eerorika Interesting. [GCC on coliru doesn't like it](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/71aa3de33f7bef59). Maybe a GCC bug fixed in a newer version?

Comment: @cdhowie I was using another language version: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/003a24f04a88d869

Comment: @cdhowie **[global.functions]/2** A call to a non-member function signature described in Clauses 21 through 33 and Annex D shall behave as if the implementation declared no additional non-member function signatures.(181) **Footnote 181**: ... An implementation may also define additional non-member functions that would otherwise not be called by a valid C++ program.

Comment: (May be) Unrelated: You shouldn't be doing this! Read more: [Can I take the address of a function defined in the standard library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55687044/can-i-take-the-address-of-a-function-defined-in-standard-library)

Comment: @JeJo Interesting, actually that seems quite related. This would fall under the umbrella of UB, it seems, so a compile-time error is probably the _best_ outcome here. I've been using C++ quite a long while and somehow never learned that taking the address of some standard library functions is UB.

Comment: While it doesn't change the UB, it should be noted that `std::swap` moved from `<algorithm>` to `<utility>` in C++11. Whether or not `<algorithm>` is included actually does affect whether I get an error, with both GCC and Clang. (e.g., [one with Clang failing](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/heWqo8) and [one with GCC compiling it](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/GfhG5q))

Comment: @cdhowie  Taking the addess of a function template _is_ UB.

Comment: @MichaëlRoy I assume you mean an instantiation of a function template. I've not seen any evidence that doing so is UB in the general case.

Comment: @cdhowie  No, I mean a template.  An instantiation of a template, like std::swap<int>, is already a function, as far as the compiler is concerned.

Comment: @MichaëlRoy Okay. So why are we talking about taking the address of a function template? It's not only UB, it's nonsense. I can't think of any compilers that will successfully compile such an operation. I can't even see where we've discussed such a thing in this thread.

Comment: I totally agree.  Maybe because T is not a concrete type, I guess.   But if blame should be given, look towards the original poster.  But in the context of a site dedicated to help solve such issues, blame is a bit too harsh of a word, isn't it?

Comment: T is no less concrete in the above situation where I mentioned that it did work.  I was asking specifically why `auto` doesn't work when that does.