# Cannot deduce function return type

Tags: c++, c++17, language-lawyer, template-argument-deduction

This doesn't work with either gcc-10 or clang-10.

```
template <typename R, typename T>
auto invoke_function(R (&f)(T), T t) { return std::invoke(f, t); }

invoke_function(std::to_string, 42);
```

This works with gcc-10, but not clang-10.

```
template <typename R, typename T>
auto invoke_function(T t, R (&f)(T)) { return std::invoke(f, t); }

invoke_function(42, std::to_string);
```

Error messages are very similar in all cases: "couldn't infer template argument 'R'" or "couldn’t deduce template parameter ‘R’" (gcc).

It isn't clear why this code is rejected. Since `T` is deduced, the overload of `std::to_string` can be determined. The dependency on argument order is particularly annoying. Shouldn't it Just Work?

I know this problem can be sidestepped by introducing a function object:

```
struct to_string
{
    template<typename T> std::string operator()(T t) { return std::to_string(t); }
};
```

and then just using `std::invoke` on it. This however requires creating a separate function object for each overload set.

Is there a better way?

Comment: No, You can not: [Can I take the address of a function defined in standard library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55687044/can-i-take-the-address-of-a-function-defined-in-standard-library). Maybe a dupe! BTW, can't we have a generic lambda instead of the functor you provided! Wouldn't be less typing?

Comment: @JeJo That doesn't seem quite relevant. The same deduction issue exists [if we use our own overload set](https://godbolt.org/z/c76aTd), and the fact that you can't form references to standard functions is just an extra layer of broken.

Comment: IIRC, the compiler is supposed to try and deduce the template parameters separately from each function parameter, and only if they match when multiple parameters share a type does deduction succeed.  I'm surprised GCC works from the second version.  Do you really need `R` and `T`?  There are multiple ways to get the return type of the function like `using return_type = decltype(f(t));` and you can use SFINAE to check if the function can be called with `t`, or static asset it to get a nice error message.

Comment: @NathanOliver "There are multiple ways to get the return type of the function" Indeed, but before getting to an individual function, we need to resolve an overload set. How do you do that? Note that every one of the functions named `std::to_string` *can* be called with an `int` argument.

Comment: Ah yes, good point.  Wasn't thinking about that part.

Comment: @JeJo Great point. A generic lambda would be an improvement indeed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> It isn't clear why this code is rejected. Since `T` is deduced, the overload of `std::to_string` can be determined.

That's not how it works exactly. Template deduction deduces each parameter/argument pair *independently* first - and then we bring all the deductions together and ensure that they're consistent. So we deduce `T` from `42` and then, separately, we deduce `R(&)(T)` from `std::to_string`. But every overload of `std::to_string` matches that pattern, so we don't know which one to pick.

But the above is only true if we *can* deduce each pair independently. If a parameter is non-deducible, we skip it and then try to go back and fill it in later. And that's the key here - we restructure the deduction such that we *only* deduce `T` from `42`:

```
template <typename T>
auto invoke_function(std::string (&f)(std::type_identity_t<T>), T t) { return std::invoke(f, t); }
```

Here, we deduce `T` and `int` and now we're deducing `std::string(&)(int)` from `std::to_string`. Which now works, because only a single overload matches that pattern.

---

Except now this is undefined behavior, as per [[namespace.std]/6](http://eel.is/c++draft/library#namespace.std-6):

> Let `F` denote a standard library function ([global.functions]), a standard library static member function, or an instantiation of a standard library function template. Unless `F` is designated an addressable function, the behavior of a C++ program is unspecified (possibly ill-formed) if it explicitly or implicitly attempts to form a pointer to `F`.

`std::to_string` is not an addressable function.

So the *real* better way is to just wrap `to_string` in a lambda and pass that along:

```
invoke_function([](auto x){ return std::to_string(x); }, 42);
```

And just adjusting `invoke_function` to take an arbitrary callable rather than specifically a function. That lambda wrapping generalizes to:

```
#define FWD(x) static_cast<decltype(x)&&>(x)
#define LIFT(name) [&](auto&&... args) noexcept(noexcept(name(FWD(args)...))) -> decltype(name(FWD(args)...)) { return name(FWD(args)...); }

invoke_function(LIFT(std::to_string), 42);
```

Comment: The two compilers give different results, why? It looks like gcc deduces the arguments in order, fist argument first and then the second using just obtained results; and clang doesn't do that.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm.Different results to what?

Comment: One compiles the function with the arguments swapped, the other doesn't.

Comment: But there is no attempt to form a pointer to `std::to_string`...

Comment: @LanguageLawyer Do you really think the rule applies _specifically_ to pointers and _not at all_ to references?

Comment: _Do you really think the rule applies specifically to pointers and not at all to references?_ What do you mean by "the rule"? The paragraph? Or the very part which speaks about pointers? If later, of course it doesn't apply to references, because references are not pointers. References are covered explicitly later in the same paragraph.

Comment: @LanguageLawyer I don't see how these sorts of comments add anything to understanding. It's like being pedantic for the sake of being pedantic.

Comment: So you say that if there were no special rule of references, you'd think that this rule also applies to references?

Comment: @LanguageLawyer Is this at all relevant to understanding the question or the answer?

Comment: Why are you answering a question with a question?

Comment: @LanguageLawyer The same result happens with user-defined overload sets. https://godbolt.org/ So non-addressability of `to_string` is not really relevant.

Comment: @Barry (1) This only works with overload sets which all return the same type, and (2) you have to mention this type explicitly. This kinda defeats the purpose. Let's do the same thing again but now with `std::abs`, or rather a wrapper around it https://godbolt.org/z/7Eo45z

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. Just don't take functions - take callables: https://godbolt.org/z/KjxnT5

Comment: @Barry Lifting an overload set to a generic lambda is a neat solution, nit what about the two compilers disagreeing about what's right and what's wrong?

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. Pretty sure gcc is wrong to accept your code - that would only be valid if it deduced `T` from the first argument and then used the result of that deduction to help deduce `R`. But that's the rules are specified - it talks about deducing all the parameters independently. In any case, it's complicated, and deducing `F` is much easier :-)

Comment: @Barry I like these. What do you think of `#define BIND_LIFT(instance, name) [&](auto&&... args) noexcept(noexcept((instance).name(FWD(args)...))) -> decltype(auto) { return (instance).name(FWD(args)...); }` to let us create a function object for a member function bound to an instance?