# Composition of functions from the standard

Tags: c++, functional-programming

I'm trying to create a function 'compose' returning the composition of callable objects given as arguments.

In mathematics, It would be the following:

```latex
F = h(g(f(x)))
```

Here an implementation in C++:

```cpp
template <typename F>
auto compose(F&& f)
{
    return[f = std::forward<F>(f)](auto&&... args){
        return f(std::forward<decltype(args)>(args)...);
    };
}

template <typename F, typename G, typename... Functions>
auto compose(F&& f, G&& g, Functions&&... functions)
{
    return compose(
        [f = std::forward<F>(f), g = std::forward<G>(g)](auto&&... args)
        {
            return f(g(std::forward<decltype(args)>(args)...));
        },
        std::forward<Functions>(functions)...);
}
```

This works like a charm if I provide lambda functions as arguments:

```cpp
auto f = compose(
    [](auto value) { return std::sin(value); },
    [](auto value) { return std::asin(value); }
);
```

However, if I use directly overloaded functions from the standard (without encapsulating them within a lambda), the compiler cannot deduce which overload to pick to instantiate the template:

```cpp
auto g = compose(
    std::sin,
    std::asin
);
```

Here the errors using Microsoft C++ compiler:

```
error C2672: 'compose': no matching overloaded function found
error C2783: 'auto compose(F &&,G &&,Functions &&...)': could not deduce template argument for 'F'
message : see declaration of 'compose'
error C2783: 'auto compose(F &&,G &&,Functions &&...)': could not deduce template argument for 'G'
message : see declaration of 'compose'
error C2780: 'auto compose(F &&)': expects 1 arguments - 2 provided
message : see declaration of 'compose'
```

Is there a way to state the function types (of std::sin and std::asin) we want to use while creating the composed function ?

Comment: I don't think there's a good way. Some use a macro to conveniently wrap functions in macros.

Comment: why not immediatly pass in your datatype, so that you can use it? eg. `compose<double>(...)`. Should work like a charm then

Comment: I'm pretty sure that should be `return g(f(std::forward<decltype(args)>(args)...));`, as you want the functions to be invoked 'from the inside out', otherwise you're calling them in the wrong order. Also, capturing by value with forwarding is pointless, and there's no need to forward here; you can safely just capture the passed-in functions by reference with `[&]`.

Comment: ...correction, capturing by reference is not safe if the composed result is going to be returned from a function, etc. in that case, the lambda in the non-base case will be a dangling reference. So we should capture by value but `move()` them rather than the extra noise of `forward()`ing.

Answer (score 2):

How about passing `(double (&)(double)) std ::sin`?

Comment: To maybe clarify a bit, there are [multiple overloads](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/sin) defined for `sin` causing deduction failure.

Comment: While this appears to work, it's actually unspecified, and is not guaranteed to work. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55687044/can-i-take-the-address-of-a-function-defined-in-standard-library

Answer (score 0):

When you call `compose` with overloaded functions, such as `std::sin`, the compiler can't deduce the type of the function you want.

One approach that *appears* to solve the problem, is forming a pointer/reference to a specific overload of the function, e.g.:

```
// wrong, though it might appear to work
auto g = compose(
    static_cast<double(&)(double)>(std::sin),
    static_cast<double(&)(double)>(std::asin)
);
```

This is not correct however, since you're not allowed to take the address of functions from `std::` that are not explicitly marked as *addressable*. The correct way to do this is in fact, the version in your question that wraps the function call in a lambda (when constructing `f`).

Note that casting to a pointer/reference to disambiguate an overload will work just fine for your own overload sets, or for functions from `std::` that are marked as *addressable*.

Comment: `std:: sin (double)` is imported from `extern "C" sin`, and that one is addressable.

Comment: @ChristopherYeleighton Hmm, maybe so, but that just means `::sin` is addressable, right? I think the c++ version is still not addressable, at least I can't find where it says that `std::sin` is addressable.

Comment: I thought `std ::sin (double)` is an alias for `::sin`?

Comment: Hmm, I don't think so, but I'm not sure. I'll have to look into this.

Comment: It's not, cmath and math.h is different. See [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/extending_std#Addressable_functions).

Comment: Of course it is different, `cmath` includes `math.h` and imports C functions into `std`.

Comment: No, I mean it's, in particular, not compatible with math.h.