# How to pass a function template as a template argument?

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, overloading, overload-resolution

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename... Args>
void print(Args const&... args)
{
    (std::cout << ... << args);
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << 1 << 2 << 3 << std::endl; // ok
    print(1, 2, 3);                        // ok
    print(1, 2, 3, std::endl);             // error! How to make it work?
}
```

See [online demo](https://godbolt.org/z/b3rqv7rTE)

**How to pass a function template as a template argument?**

Comment: It'll work if you do `print(1, 2, 3, std::endl<char, std::char_traits<char>>);`, but you probably want a way to not have to write all that extra stuff.

Comment: Tricky... I probably would fall back to `'\n'` (instead of `std::endl`).

Comment: Like @Scheff'sCat says, use `\n`,   `print(1, 2, 3, '\n');` unless you absolutely _must_ flush the stream too.

Comment: That’s not a *template* argument.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You will have the same issue with other io manipulators that typically are functions that take the stream as parameter, when they are templates. Though you can wrap them in a non-template callable:

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename... Args>
void print(Args const&... args)
{
    (std::cout << ... << args);
}
    
int main()
{
    std::cout << 1 << 2 << 3 << std::endl; // ok
    print(1, 2, 3);                        // ok
    print(1, 2, 3, [](std::ostream& o) -> std::ostream&{ 
               o << std::endl; 
               return o;
    });             // no error!
}
```

[Output](https://godbolt.org/z/5WTcTs8YP):

```
123
123123
```

The syntax is rather heavy so you might want to use a helper type, though I'll leave it to you to write that (just joking, I don't think it is trivial, but I might give it a try later ;). After pondering about it for a while, I am almost certain that there are only the two alternatives: Instantiate the function (see [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68665745/4117728)), or wrap the call inside a lambda, unless you want to write a wrapper for each single io manipulator of course.

Answer (score 7):

Here a way:

```
print(1, 2, 3, std::endl<char, std::char_traits<char>>);
```

Consider using `'\n'` instead.

Comment: [`'\n'` does not flush buffer, but `std::endl` does!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/213907/stdendl-vs-n). What if OP wants that! Also have a look: [Can I take the address of a function defined in standard library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55687044/can-i-take-the-address-of-a-function-defined-in-standard-library). Therefore, packing into a lambda is the better way.

Comment: You mostly only want a \n and if you also want to flush the buffer, do that explicitly. That is why I said "consider using" not "you should"

Comment: About taking address of the function, that's how "std::endl" works.

Comment: [You shouldn't take the address of a standard library function (or template)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55687045/5376789).

Comment: @xskxzr: That [doesn’t apply to the unary manipulators](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/extending_std#Addressable_functions).

Answer (score 5):

You cannot take address of most standard functions (see [can-i-take-the-address-of-a-function-defined-in-standard-library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55687044/can-i-take-the-address-of-a-function-defined-in-standard-library)).

Fortunately, io-manipulator is part of the exception (See [Addressable_functions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/extending_std#Addressable_functions)).

`std::endl` is a template function, so you would have to select the correct overload.

```
using print_manip_t = std::ostream& (*) (std::ostream&);

print(1, 2, 3, print_manip_t{std::endl});
print(1, 2, 3, static_cast<print_manip_t>(std::endl));
print(1, 2, 3, static_cast<std::ostream& (*) (std::ostream&)>(std::endl));
```

else you have to specify which one you want

```
print(1, 2, 3, std::endl<char, std::char_traits<char>>);
```

or wrap it

```
print(1, 2, 3, [](std::ostream& o) -> std::ostream&{ return o << std::endl; });
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/855aejfE5)

Comment: Also, would be a good suggestion: "[Can I take the address of a function defined in standard library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55687044/can-i-take-the-address-of-a-function-defined-in-standard-library)."