# Use specific std::get overload in a function

Tags: c++, templates, stl

I have a vector `std::vector<std::pair<int, bool>> vec` and I would like to know how many elemnts have the boolean set to true.  The following code works:

```
std::count_if(vec.begin(), vec.end(), [](const auto& x) { return std::get<bool>(x); });
```

However, it bothers me that I'm creating a lambda that does nothing more than call another function with the exact same parameter.  I expected that I would be able to write:

```
std::count_if(vec.begin(), vec.end(), std::get<bool>);
```

But I get a message that the compiler cannot resolve the `_Predicate` template.  I understand this to be because the compiler cannot resolve the highly overloaded `std::get` function in this context.  Is there a way to specify the correct version of `std::get` beyond wrapping it inside the lambda?

Comment: *"However, it bothers me"* - Why? And please don't say "efficiency". This idiom is very prone to inlining. But even then, you'd be told to measure carefully.

Comment: Even solving the overload issue, see [can-i-take-the-address-of-a-function-defined-in-standard-library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55687044/can-i-take-the-address-of-a-function-defined-in-standard-library).

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica: and passing lambda is even more prone to inlining than function pointer :)

Comment: @rprospero: it would be something like `static_cast<bool (*)(const std::pair<int, bool>&)>(std::get<bool>)` (if allowed for `std::get`). lambda seems better ;)

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica honestly, my co-workers all thought that the second version was clearer to read, but the linked answer obviously shows that it's not legal syntax, so our legibility concerns are moot.