# How to replace "float (*fSqrt)(float)" with "std::function<float(float) fSqrt>"?

Tags: c++, function, c++11, templates, std-function

I have a function with signature:

```
template<class Type> 
bool isPrime(const Type& n,float (*fSqrt)(float),bool debug = false)
```

Which works fine. But,

```
template<class Type> 
bool isPrime(const Type& n,std::function<float(float)> fSqrt,bool debug = false)
```

causes compile-error.

How to replace `float (*fSqrt)(float)` with `std::function<float(float)> fSqrt` ?
Please note: my ultimate objective is `std::function<float(Type)>`, where **Type** is templated.

Wandbox (https://wandbox.org/) shows:

```
prog.cc: In function 'int main()':
prog.cc:91:28: error: no matching function for call to 'isPrime(int&, <unresolved overloaded function type>, bool)'
   91 |         std::cout<<(isPrime(n,std::sqrt,true)?"Positive":"Negative")<<'\n';
      |                     ~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
prog.cc:10:27: note: candidate: 'template<class Type> bool isPrime(const Type&, const float&, bool)'
   10 | template<class Type> bool isPrime(const Type& n,const float& nSqrt = 0.0,bool debug = false) {
      |                           ^~~~~~~
prog.cc:10:27: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
prog.cc:91:28: note:   cannot convert 'std::sqrt' (type '<unresolved overloaded function type>') to type 'const float&'
   91 |         std::cout<<(isPrime(n,std::sqrt,true)?"Positive":"Negative")<<'\n';
      |                     ~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
prog.cc:81:27: note: candidate: 'template<class Type> bool isPrime(const Type&, std::function<float(float)>, bool)'
   81 | template<class Type> bool isPrime(const Type& n,std::function<float(float)> fSqrt,bool debug = false) {    // Type & std::function - compile-error
      |                           ^~~~~~~
prog.cc:81:27: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
prog.cc:91:28: note:   cannot convert 'std::sqrt' (type '<unresolved overloaded function type>') to type 'std::function<float(float)>'
   91 |         std::cout<<(isPrime(n,std::sqrt,true)?"Positive":"Negative")<<'\n';
      |                     ~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

OnlineGDB (https://www.onlinegdb.com/#) shows:

```
main.cpp:91:38: error: no matching function for call to ‘isPrime(int&, , bool)’
  std::cout<<(isPrime(n,std::sqrt,true)?"Positive":"Negative")<<'\n';
                                      ^
main.cpp:10:27: note: candidate: template bool isPrime(const Type&, const float&, bool)
 template<class Type> bool isPrime(const Type& n,const float& nSqrt = 0.0,bool debug = false) {
                           ^~~~~~~
main.cpp:10:27: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
main.cpp:91:38: note:   cannot convert ‘sqrt’ (type ‘’) to type ‘const float&’
  std::cout<<(isPrime(n,std::sqrt,true)?"Positive":"Negative")<<'\n';
                                      ^
main.cpp:81:27: note: candidate: template bool isPrime(const Type&, std::function, bool)
 template<class Type> bool isPrime(const Type& n,std::function<float(float)> fSqrt,bool debug = false) {    // Type & std::function - compile-error
                           ^~~~~~~
main.cpp:81:27: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
main.cpp:91:38: note:   cannot convert ‘sqrt’ (type ‘’) to type ‘std::function’
  std::cout<<(isPrime(n,std::sqrt,true)?"Positive":"Negative")<<'\n';
                                      ^
```

Comment: `sqrt` is overloaded, you have to cast it `static_cast<float(*)(float)>(std::sqrt)` to select the proper one.

Comment: Just change `std::sqrt` to `::sqrt`.

Answer (score 3):

As others have pointed out [`std::sqrt`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/sqrt) has multiple overload, and you should specify which one to deduce there to be a `std:.function`. For example `static_cast<float(*)(float)>(std::sqrt)`.

However, you should not be taking the address of a standard library function.
See in detail here:
[Can I take the address of a function defined in standard library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55687044/can-i-take-the-address-of-a-function-defined-in-standard-library)

Secondly the [`std::function` comes with a type-erasure overhead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5057382/what-is-the-performance-overhead-of-stdfunction).

Therefore, I suggest packing the `std::sqrt` to a lambda, and use template argument to deduce the lambda by the compiler. Something like

```
template<class Type, typename Callable> 
bool isPrime(const Type& n, Callable fSqrt, bool debug = false)
{
    // ...
}
```

and call via

```
isPrime(2.f, [](float val) { return std::sqrt(val); });
```

---

However, now `isPrime` takes anything callable. This can be restricted only for the specific one by sfinaeing the function.

```
#include <type_traits> // std::enable_if, std::is_floating, std::invoke_result

template<class Type, typename Callable> 
auto isPrime(const Type& n, Callable fSqrt, bool debug = false)
->std::enable_if_t<std::is_floating_point_v<std::invoke_result_t<Callable, Type>>, bool>
{
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks @JeJo. 
[1.] Already got `static_assert (std::is_integral<Type>::value,"ERR: integral type required");` in place. 
[2.] Why can't the compiler deduce this `static_cast<float(*)(float)>(std::sqrt)` ?