# Why passing `printf` as template function argument succeeds but `cos` failed (msvc 19)?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I am playing with online c++ compilers a little bit on [link](https://godbolt.org/z/93rb8E3ch). But the code snippet below got failed when compiled with msvc v19.latest.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdio>

template<class F, class...L>
void test(F f, L...args) {
    std::cout<< "res = " << f(args...) << '\n';
}


int main() 
{
    test(cos, 0.1);   #1
    test(printf, "%s", "aaa");   #2
}
```

How could it be that line #2 is ok and line #1 can't get a pass?

MSVC is happy with the following code but this time it's GCC's turn to reject it. MSVC's iostream file includes cmath header and GCC #undefs cos :)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
//#include <iostream>

template<class F, class...L>
void test(F f, L...args) {
    f(args...);
}

int main() 
{
    test(cos, 0.1);
    test(printf, "%s", "aaa");
}
```

Since c++20, there's another issue raised in the second answer and has been addressed in this question [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55687044/can-i-take-the-address-of-a-function-defined-in-standard-library)

Comment: Your godbolt link is to the default landing page. You need to choose **share** for a permalink.

Comment: There is only one `printf` function.  `cos` is overloaded and you need to specify which overload you want.

Comment: Also note that just using `cos` is not portable.  `cmath` is not required to expose any functions in the global namespace.  If fact, if you make it correct by using `std::cos`, gcc will also fail to compile the code: https://godbolt.org/z/q1q5qcjva

Comment: `test(static_cast<double(*)(double)>(&std::cos), 0.1);`

Comment: @Eljay: Is `cos` in the allowed functions for which we can take address of?

Comment: @Jarod42 • oooooh.... I don't know, I bet you're right.  I can on my compiler, but I wrote my compiler (forked from clang) -- and it's not an intrinsic on mine.  And I don't have `::cos` or `::printf` polluting the global namespace either, so I had to add the `std::` for both.  It is likely one of those rascally "functions" that can be inlined as a single instruction intrinsic for real compilers versus my Frankenstein's monster compiler.

Comment: `test([](double d) { return std::cos(d); }, 0.1);` should mitigate the problem that Jarod42 mentioned.

Comment: @Eljay lambda is good, just let the compilers do the deduction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is failing because `cos` is an overloaded function in msvc. This means that there  are at least 3 different versions of `cos`:

```
float cos(float arg);
double cos(double arg);
long double cos(long double arg);
```

The compiler has no way of guessing which one you are trying to use, but you can give it a hand by using `static_cast` like the following:

```
int main()
{
    test(static_cast<double(*)(double)>(cos), 0.1);
    test(printf, "%s", "aaa");   
}
```

Comment: I am naively thinking that msvc will compile successfully as gcc and clang do :) anyway thanks for the point. by the way, a curious question: why gcc and clang and icc happily go with it even without issuing a warning?

Comment: @HuFellan, it looks like gcc and clang do not have the overloaded functions. See what happens if you compile the [following](https://tio.run/##ZYsxDsIwDEV3n8ISS4KEegCgdwlOQiMSu2ocdUCcPVTtwMDf3td7NM8Xyo6fvZ8SU24@4C1J1SW4MsLvo@J0GgESKxaX2FiEN@A2L@2RA5qzj43JmoMt3pGkXnEYUKdUcZXlVfcgZnG6@fHwd/zTvYSKLAqf3r8) in gcc and msvc

Comment: Seems you are right gcc's error shows that cos's prototype is this: double (*)(double) noexcept

Comment: @HuFellan, it looks like `std::cos` is overloaded in `gcc` but not `cos`. Strange...

Comment: By reading (https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/cos/) it's clear that gcc also has its overloads but located in std namespace. A raw cos, gcc regards it as you are referring to the global one: double cos (double x);

Comment: @HuFellan, sometimes gcc and msvc do not comply with the reference. have a look at this: [https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/from_chars](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/from_chars) and then try to use `from_chars` with a double in gcc...

Answer (score 1):

It is [not allowed](http://eel.is/c++draft/namespace.std#6) to take an address of a library function (with a few exceptions), and thus to pass it as an argument to another function. Any attempt to do so is *unspecified behaviour*. MSVC is right to reject your program, and gcc is also right to accept it (and perhaps format your hard disk and send nasty emails to your boss).

Comment: For msvc, passing printf is also ok?

Comment: @HuFellan The standard says it is *unspecified*. A specific compiler may say "it is actually ok", or "no, don't do that", or just say nothing and let you figure it out.