# How to do a callback using a std::function() as reference?

Tags: c++, callback

I want to write a callback like this

```
template<typename T>
T GetValue(T (*CallBack) (const string), string in)
{
    T value;

    try
    {
        value = CallBack(in);
    }
    catch(std::invalid_argument &e)///if no conversion could be performed
    {
        cout << "Error: invalid argument: --> " + string(e.what());
        exit(-1);
    }
    return value;
}

int main()
{
    int integer=0;
    string data;
    cin>>data;
    integer=GetValue<int>(&std::stoi, data);
    return 0;
}
```

but it does not works. I have the following error.

> error: cannot convert "|unresolved overloaded function type|" to "int
> (^)(std::string)" {aka int (^)(std::__cxx11::basic_string)}

I tried other ways too. Like this:

```
class Object;
typedef int (Object::*CallBack)(const string&, std::size_t*, int);
```

Or like this:

```
    typedef int (std::*FCAST)(const string&);
    std::function<int(const string&)> f = (FCAST)&std::stoi;
```

> error: address of overloaded function with no contextual type
> information|

But i had not success. ¿Someone knows how to do it?

Thank you so much!!

Comment: std::stoi doesn't expect string passed as call by value I guess. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol. But of course that doesn't seem to be the root cause of this issue.

Comment: Yes, i think so too. Than you so much for your response and the link

Comment: `std::stoi` has a type. It is not `int (*) (const string)`. It is not `int (Object::*)(const string&, std::size_t*, int)`. It is not `int(const string&)`. Just use the right type. https://godbolt.org/z/Mvh4bqhxP Note that it is **undefined behaviour** to take an address of most standard library functions.

Comment: It works. Thank you so much. Very appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Link: https://godbolt.org/z/69fTzW36z

You have to use the correct function signature - the one which `stoi` has.

As per this link: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol, the signrature is `int stoi(const string&, size_t* pos = nullptr, int base = 10)`

So making the changes (see `// CHANGE HERE`)

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

// CHANGE HERE: see the function arguments to Callback
template<typename T>
T GetValue(T (*CallBack) (const string&, size_t* pos, int base), const string& in)
{
    T value;

    try
    {
        // CHANGE HERE: pass default arguments when calling the function
        value = CallBack(in, nullptr, 10);
    }
    catch(std::invalid_argument &e)///if no conversion could be performed
    {
        cout << "Error: invalid argument: --> " + string(e.what());
        exit(-1);
    }
    return value;
}

int main()
{
    int integer=0;
    string data = "1234";
    //cin>>data;
    integer=GetValue<int>(std::stoi, data);
    cout << integer << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

As mentioned in the comments, it's better not to use standard library functions directly as function callbacks. Rather you may implement your own logic or you can use some other way like lambda functions, something like:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template<typename T>
T GetValue(T (*CallBack) (const string&), const string& in)
{
    T value;

    try
    {
        value = CallBack(in);
    }
    catch(std::invalid_argument &e)///if no conversion could be performed
    {
        cout << "Error: invalid argument: --> " + string(e.what());
        exit(-1);
    }
    return value;
}

int main()
{
    string data = "1234";
    //cin>>data;
    int integer = GetValue<int>([](const string& s) { return stoi(s); }, data);
    cout << integer << endl;
    string data2 = "12345678900";
    long l = GetValue<long>([](const string& s) { return stol(s); }, data2);
    cout << l << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Link: https://godbolt.org/z/31oKx5cjE

Comment: Note that `std::stoi` is not designated an [addressable function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/extending_std#Addressing_restriction). Use a lambda instead to avoid unspecified behavior. See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/55687044/1458097

Comment: Yes that's correct. Let me try to make some changes.

Answer (score 2):

If you look at [`std::stoi`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol), the signature is `int(const std::string&, std::size_t*, int );` So, your callback needs to be of the right type. If you want to use the default parameter value, you can use lambdas.

`GetValue<int>([](std::string s) { return std::stoi(s); }, data);`

Comment: Thank you so much for your response too. It is a very good alternative way.