# Is MSVC correct in refusing to compile this code?

Tags: c++, c++17, language-lawyer

Consider this code ([godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/vzb96s41b)):

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <memory>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

template<auto L, class T = decltype(L)>
using constant = integral_constant<T, L>;

int main() 
{
    unique_ptr<void, constant<&free>> p1;
    unique_ptr<void, constant<free>> p2;    // <-- MSVC refuses to compile this line
    return 0;
}
```

Why does MSVC refuse to compile the highlighted line? Is this code valid?

MSVC produces:

```
<source>(13): error C2975: 'L': invalid template argument for 'constant', expected compile-time constant expression
<source>(7): note: see declaration of 'L'
```

Comment: It just says "I refuse"?

Comment: @jarmod My bad. Fixed...

Comment: `::free` and `std::free` compile, so `free` might be being replaced by some compiler intrinsic

Comment: Removing `using namespace std;` and qualifying `unique_ptr` with `std::` accordingly also makes the program compile. `free` may simply alias the C lib version which has C language linkage, but that shouldn't matter for an `auto` non-type template parameter (but does for when trying to assign to function pointer with C++ language linkage a function address with language linkage, maybe this plays into the apparent buggy behaviour here).

Comment: [Why is "using namespace std;" considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/995714)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pre-C++20 it looks like a MSVC bug.

After C++20, [the behavior is unspecified](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/extending_std#Addressing_restriction) (thanks @heapunderrun)
since `free` is not in the list of functions you're allowed to take the addresses of. But I'd argue that it's still a bug (even if conformant), since MSVC lets you take the address of the same function if you use `&`.

---

Template argument deduction in this case is done as if by `constexpr auto x = free;` ([`[temp.arg.nontype]/1`](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.arg.nontype#1)), and the above declaration is accepted by MSVC, deducing a function pointer.

Some implicit conversions are banned when passing a template argument, the allowed conversions are listed in [`[expr.const]/10`](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.const#10.4) and include a "function-to-pointer conversion".

Comment: Any idea why `::free` works for MSVC and `free` -- doesn't?

Comment: @C.M. Possibly this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55687044/can-i-take-the-address-of-a-function-defined-in-standard-library as `free` is `std::free` because of `using namespace std;`

Comment: But is such function-to-pointer conversion still guaranteed to succeed here, taking into account that `std::free` is **not** among the designated [addressable functions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/extending_std#Addressing_restriction)?

Comment: So, in C++20 they made it harder to make those auto-release objects (that require `free` or whatever) again... sigh...