# Why doesn't std::integral_constant<lambda> work the same way as std::integral_constant<function-ptr>?

Tags: c++, c++17, language-lawyer

(related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70993273/is-msvc-correct-in-refusing-to-compile-this-code)).

I am trying to combine `unique_ptr` and lambda via `std::integral_constant` (taking address of most std functions is outlawed in C++20, I am figuring out a convenient way to wrap them in lambda). I noticed weird behaviour of `std::integral_constant` that I can't explain ([godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/4Gr8Khdcd)):

```
#include <type_traits>

template<auto L, class T = decltype(L)>
using constant = std::integral_constant<T, L>;

void dummy(void*);

int main() 
{
    using C1 = constant<&dummy>;
    using C2 = constant<[](void* p){ dummy(p); }>;

    C1()()(nullptr);        // #1 works as expected
    C2()()(nullptr);        // #2 works as expected

    C1()(nullptr);          // #3 unexpectedly works
    C2()(nullptr);          // #4 fails as expected

    return 0;
}
```

Can someone explain why line #3 compiles? This is what `std::unique_ptr` uses under cover (when you use `std::integral_constant` as deleter) and this is why my attempts to use lambda instead of function address fail.

P.S. Line #4 fails with following message:

```
<source>: In function 'int main()':
<source>:17:17: error: no match for call to '(C2 {aka std::integral_constant<const main()::<lambda(void*)>, <lambda closure object>main()::<lambda(void*)>{}>}) (std::nullptr_t)'
   17 |     C2()(nullptr);          // #4 fails as expected
```

Comment: Implicit conversion (`operator value_type ()`) happens.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When performing a function call on an object, not only the call operators are considered. There is a special exception if a non-explicit conversion function to a function pointer type (or function reference type) with suitable cvref-qualifiers exists.

In these situations [[over.call.object]/2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/over.call.object#2) says that an additional overload is generated, a *surrogate call function* which takes the converted implicit object pointer as first argument and the function pointer/reference's parameters as further parameters. If this overload is chosen, it will use the conversion function to convert `this` to the function pointer/reference and then call it with the remaining provided arguments.

`std::integral_constant` has a non-explicit conversion function to `value_type` and so if `value_type` is a function pointer/reference, and only then, will this surrogate call exist, which essentially forwards the object function call to a call to the stored function pointer/reference.

Comment: Woah... That is one weird rule. I wonder if it needs to be expanded with `... or or the type “[reference to] lambda <blah-blah>”`? Since lambdas are effectively functions...

Comment: @C.M. The rule is already in C++98. It is very specific. Maybe noone has bothered proposing to include lambdas? The rule also doesn't seem to properly forward the value category of the arguments, another C++11 feature for which it seems to not have been updated.

Comment: @C.M. no, lambdas are not "effectively functions". That's a wrong generalization. Lambdas create closure objects. That's much more complex.

Comment: @JHBonarius It looks like this rule was introduced to allow function pointers to be magically called in such situations. I think, in this context extending this magic to lambdas makes sense (even though they are significantly more complicated). Or remove this rule altogether and/or replace it (in `unique_ptr/etc`) with mechanism that recognizes callable objects.

Comment: @C.M. Regarding `std::unqiue_ptr`: You just have to define your own `std::integral_constant` whose `operator()` forwards the arguments to the stored object, rather than returning the object. Then it will work as deleter.

Comment: @user17732522 Yes, or event better: `unique_ptr<void, decltype([](void*){ ... })>`, maybe add some utility that will make making these more convenient...

Comment: Comically, [explicitly casting lambda to function pointer](https://godbolt.org/z/PnE337c4b) fixes MSVC, but breaks GCC...

Comment: @C.M. Seems to be [this bug in GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=83258).

Comment: @user17732522 Thank you