# Is it possible to pass one of the standard function templates as an argument without using a lambda?

Tags: c++

For example, `std::get<N>`.

Can I do the following without using a lambda somehow?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

using str_and_int = std::tuple<std::string, int>;

std::vector<std::string> just_strings(const std::vector<str_and_int>& tuples) {
    std::vector<std::string> strings(tuples.size());
    std::transform(tuples.begin(), tuples.end(), strings.begin(),
        [](const auto& tup) {
            return std::get<0>(tup);
        }
    );
    return strings;
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<str_and_int> foo = { {"foo",1}, {"bar",2} ,{"quux",3}, {"mumble",4} };
    for (const auto& str : just_strings(foo)) {
        std::cout << str << "\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Changing it to

```
std::transform(tuples.begin(), tuples.end(), strings.begin(), std::get<0, str_and_int>)
```

does not work. I am guessing because `std::get` is overloaded?

Comment: You can pass a function pointer if that helps. (So first try to store the function pointer in a variable and see what error you have.)

Comment: @lorro but you can't take the address of [most functions in `std`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55687044/can-i-take-the-address-of-a-function-defined-in-standard-library)

Comment: why do you want to avoid using a lambda? I mean you can write your custom function or functor, but not sure if thats what you are looking for.

Comment: yeah
`std::string(*fn)(const str_and_int&) = std::get<0, str_and_int>;`
yields basically the same error. Visual Studio says "cannot convert from overloaded function"

Comment: because I tend to always use lambdas when using the standard algorithms even when I don't have to and I am trying to get out of that habit. Like if you have a free function that has the signature a standard algorithm needs you should just use that, not wrap it in a lambda. I am going through code and removing redundant lambdas. This case I can't fix though but like std::get<0> here should instantiate to some kind of callable that can be used I just dont know if there is syntax that allows using that callable.

Comment: the callable you are looking for is the lambda. Lambdas play extremely well with compiler optimizations like inlining, I doubt you can find something better

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't *have* to use a lambda. You could provide an instance of your own type if you'd like:

```
struct transformer {
    auto operator()(const auto& tup) const { // auto C++20
        return std::get<0>(tup);
    }
};

std::vector<std::string> just_strings(const std::vector<str_and_int>& tuples) {
    std::vector<std::string> strings(tuples.size());
    std::transform(tuples.begin(), tuples.end(), strings.begin(), transformer{});
    return strings;
}
```

Comment: this answers the question as asked but i think the real answer i was looking for is no. if it is not allowed to get a pointer to a function in the standard library then when you pass one as an argument you have to wrap it in something, like in this answer or in a lambda. There's no magic syntax to refer to what std::get<0> instantiates into in the code in the question though.

Comment: @jwezorek No, that's true. I've taken the address of standard functions myself in the past (before I realized I shouldn't) and I got so surprised that it worked in some cases in some implementations and not in others.

Answer (score 0):

Because it is illegal to get a pointer to a function in the standard library, a less verbose option if you are doing this sort of thing multiple times is to wrap the call in a function template. For example,

```
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

using str_and_int = std::tuple<std::string, int>;

template <typename T>
auto first(const T& tup) {
    return std::get<0>(tup);
}

std::vector<std::string> just_strings(const std::vector<str_and_int>& tuples) {
    std::vector<std::string> strings(tuples.size());
    std::transform(tuples.begin(), tuples.end(), strings.begin(), first<str_and_int> );
    return strings;
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<str_and_int> foo = { {"foo",1}, {"bar",2} ,{"quux",3}, {"mumble",4} };
    for (const auto& str : just_strings(foo)) {
        std::cout << str << "\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```