# Problem using std::transform with lambdas VS std::transform with std::bind

Tags: c++, lambda, clang, c++20, stdbind

I am using Clang 14.0.0 and C++20. My goal is to write a general function in order to use [`std::lerp`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/lerp) on a set of elements. So I came up with this:

```
template <typename InputIterator, typename OutputIterator>
constexpr OutputIterator
lerp_element(InputIterator first, InputIterator last, OutputIterator result, 
             std::iter_value_t<InputIterator> const& a, 
             std::iter_value_t<InputIterator> const& b)
{
    return std::transform(first, last, result, [&a, &b] (auto const &t) { return std::lerp(a, b, t); });
}
```

This works well, however - in an attempt to find a better/alternative way - I thought that maybe a version with [`std::bind`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind) could be more concise and elegant:

```
template <typename InputIterator, typename OutputIterator>
constexpr
OutputIterator
lerp_element(InputIterator first, InputIterator last, OutputIterator result, 
             std::iter_value_t<InputIterator> const& a, 
             std::iter_value_t<InputIterator> const& b)
{
    return std::transform(first, last, result, std::bind(std::lerp(a, b, std::placeholders::_3)));
}
```

Lastly I found that [`std::bind_front`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind_front) allows me to be even less verbose:

```
template <typename InputIterator, typename OutputIterator>
constexpr
OutputIterator
lerp_element(InputIterator first, InputIterator last, OutputIterator result, 
             std::iter_value_t<InputIterator> const& a, 
             std::iter_value_t<InputIterator> const& b)
{
    return std::transform(first, last, result, std::bind_front(std::lerp(a, b)));
}
```

The problem is when I try to compile the two latter versions (the ones that use `std::bind` and `std::bind_front`), Clang throws this error message at me:

[image]

Here is the calling code:

```
int main() {
    
    std::vector<double> v = { 0.11, 0.53, 0.32, 0.29, 0.77, 0.45, 0.96, 0.0, 1.0 };
    std::vector<double> results;

    lerp_element(std::begin(v), std::end(v), std::back_inserter(results), 10.0, 20.0);
    for (auto x : results) { std::cout << x << ' '; }
 
    return 0;
}
```

[Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/6aKPozdbq)

Since I have the version with the lambda working, it seems the issue must be in the way I am using `std::bind`. I have been reading everything I could find online on how to properly use `std::bind` and `std::placeholders`, but obviously I must not be getting it.

I understand the problem has to do with `std::lerp` not receiving consistent argument types in order to resolve the overload, so:

1. why does that happen?
2. how do I modify the `std::bind`/`std::bind_front` versions to make it compile and work as expected?

Comment: In your case, lambda is the better and simpler solution.

Comment: Yes, I have to agree.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function argument to [`std::bind`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind) or [`std::bind_front`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind_front) should not be invoked, but rather the function itself is passed as the first argument:

```cpp
using T = std::iter_value_t<InputIterator>;
using F = T (*)(T, T, T) noexcept;

return std::transform(first, last, result,
                      std::bind_front<F>(std::lerp, a, b));
```

[Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/hPx7P6W3E)

Comment: Yes, that's it. Thanks Patrick. As outlined in the comments, it seems that the lambda solution is the simplest and clearest one in this case.

Comment: BTW, bind versions are UB, as taking most std function addresses isn't allowed.

Comment: @Jarod42 thanks for the tip, just found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55687044) after reading your comment. I wasn't familiar with that rule given that most of the code I've written has specifically targeted clang and/or gcc, and both their implementations pretty consistently use addressable functions throughout.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts there are a huge number of different functions denoted by `std::lerp`. how does `std::bind_front`'s argument deduction know which to pick?