# std::bind with std::shared_ptr works on gcc/clang, but not on msvc

Tags: c++, templates, bind, member-functions

The following code can be compiled with g++ 8.1.0 and clang 10.0.0.

```
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

int main() {
    auto dereference = std::bind(
        &std::shared_ptr<int>::operator*,
        std::placeholders::_1);

    std::shared_ptr<int> sp = std::make_shared<int>(10);
    std::cout << dereference(sp) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

However, msvc in vs2022 reports the following error:

```
example.cpp<source>(6): error C2672: 'std::bind': no matching overloaded function foundC:/data/msvc/14.34.31931-Pre/include\functional(2029): note: could be 'std::_Binder<_Ret,_Fx,_Types...> std::bind(_Fx &&,_Types &&...)'<source>(8): 
note: 'std::_Binder<_Ret,_Fx,_Types...> std::bind(_Fx &&,_Types &&...)': could not deduce template argument for '_Ret'<source>(8): note: 'std::_Binder<_Ret,_Fx,_Types...> std::bind(_Fx &&,_Types &&...)': could not deduce template argument for '_Fx'C:/data/msvc/14.34.31931-Pre/include\functional(2024): note: or       'std::_Binder<std::_Unforced,_Fx,_Types...> std::bind(_Fx &&,_Types &&...)'<source>(8): note: 'std::_Binder<std::_Unforced,_Fx,_Types...> std::bind(_Fx &&,_Types &&...)': could not deduce template argument for '_Fx'<source>(11): error C3536: 'dereference': cannot be used before it is initialized<source>(11): error C2064: term does not evaluate to a function taking 1 argumentsCompiler returned: 2
```

Is it a bug of msvc compiler or the above code can be fixed?

To reproduce the compile error, you can go to https://godbolt.org/ for details.

Comment: _can the above code be fixed?_  Certainly - try using a lambda instead, `std::bind` is pretty much obsolete these days.

Comment: Congrats on posting a nice [mre], BTW

Comment: this compile (msvc) : 
<code>auto dereference = std::bind( &std::shared_ptr<int>::operator*<>, std::placeholders::_1);</code>

Comment: add <> solve the problem, and I think lambda is a better choice. Thank you guys.

Comment: IIRC all functions/methods of std are to be considered callables, i.e., one can call them but getting pointer/reference is illegal according to standart.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Behavior is unspecified when trying to take the address of a member function of a standard library class. This allows the standard library to choose a different number or different declarations for the overloads of the member function, as long as direct calls still behave as specified by the standard. For example if the implementation chooses to implement `operator*` with multiple overloads, then taking the address for `std::bind` won't work since there is no way to deduce which of the overloads you mean.

Instead of `std::bind` use a lambda that doesn't require taking the address of a function. `std::bind` is pretty out-dated anyway and lambdas are much simpler to use:

```
auto dereference = [](auto&& p)->decltype(auto){ return *decltype(p)(p); };
```

This works for any type and also does perfect-forwarding correctly. If you don't want that you can specify a type explicitly instead of `auto` and you can replace `decltype(p)(p)` with `p` if you don't want perfect-forwarding. You might also want to add a `noexcept` specification.

`->decltype(auto)` makes it so that the value category for the function call is also replicated exactly, meaning that if `operator*` returns a reference, so will the lambda. Without it the lambda will always return by-value. Which one you want depends on the purpose of this callable.

Answer (score 1):

Taking the address of a function in standard library apart. [You should not do this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55687044/can-i-take-the-address-of-a-function-defined-in-standard-library)

Assume that you can safely take the address. (which is not).

In MSVC, this function member is overloaded for reasons. You cannot [take the address of a overloaded function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/overloaded_address), unless, roughly, a conversion sequence is formed one way or another. Unfortunately, this is not the case when calling `std::bind`.

You can verify if a function member is overloaded by trying

```
auto addr = &std::shared_ptr<int>::operator*;
```

A way to get the address of a overloaded member is to cast it explicitly yourself(specify which overload you would like to refer). `static_cast<int &(std::shared_ptr<int>::*)() const noexcept>(&std::shared_ptr<int>::operator*)`. As member `std::shared_ptr<int>::operator*` should have a signature `T& operator*() const noexcept` according to the standard.

Not a fix:

```
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

int main() {
    auto dereference = std::bind(
        static_cast<int &(std::shared_ptr<int>::*)() const noexcept>(&std::shared_ptr<int>::operator*),
        std::placeholders::_1);

    std::shared_ptr<int> sp = std::make_shared<int>(10);
    std::cout << dereference(sp) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```