# ::tolower using std::transform

Tags: c++, transform, std, tolower

Why std::transform doesn't work this way:

```
std::string tmp = "WELCOME";
std::string out = "";
std::transform(tmp.begin(), tmp.end(), out.begin(), ::tolower);
```

out is empty!

But this works:

```
std::transform(tmp.begin(), tmp.end(), tmp.begin(), ::tolower);
```

I don't want the transformation to happen in-place.

Comment: C++ algorithms assign to ranges. There has *to be* a range there to assign. An empty string is an empty range. Mind however that there is a wee bit of undefined behavior in your code snippet.

Comment: You need to pass `back_inserter`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are writing in out-of-bounds memory, since the range of `out` is smaller than that of `tmp`. You can store the result in `out` by applying [`std::back_inserter`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/back_inserter).

As user17732522 pointed out, since [it's not legal to take the adress of a standard libary function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55687044/can-i-take-the-address-of-a-function-defined-in-standard-library), it's better to pass over a lamda object that calls `std::tolower` on the character when needed.

```
std::transform(tmp.begin(), tmp.end(), std::back_inserter(out), [](auto c) {
    return std::tolower(static_cast<unsigned char>(c));
});
```

Comment: [`std::tolower`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/tolower) is even worst: *"the behavior of `std::tolower` is undefined if the argument's value is neither representable as `unsigned char` nor equal to EOF"*, some cast to `unsigned char`/ from `int` is required.

Comment: @Jarod42 That applies to both `::tolower` and `std::tolower` and all of the functions from `<cctype>`/`<ctype.h>`. It would be practically always wrong to call these functions without cast, but it seems that often  the non-ASCII case is simply ignored.

Comment: @StackDanny If you want to have this be correct even for the non-ASCII characters, then `auto` or `char` will not do. The parameter has to have type `unsigned char` (or it must be cast to it before passing to `tolower`). I neglected that in my previous deleted comment.

Comment: I guess I have been using `tolower` recklessly all the time. I wonder why the decision was not to define for `std::string::value_type`, ergo `char`.

Answer (score 3):

One way is to resize the string to allocate sufficient memory for `std::transform` to populate it.

```
out.resize(tmp.size()); // <---
std::transform(tmp.begin(), tmp.end(), out.begin(), ::tolower);
```

Alternatively, as others have mentioned you could use `std::back_inserter`, which handles inserting for you. We can also call `out.reserve` to save time on allocations (especially if your string is large).

```
out.reserve(tmp.size()); // (optional) Smol optimisation.
std::transform(tmp.begin(), tmp.end(), std::back_inserter(out), ::tolower);
```

Comment: This will usually work, but the behavior is still technically unspecified if a standard library function like `::tolower` is passed directly. A lambda calling the function should be passed instead.