# Why std::isupper can not apply to std::any_of directly but isupper(from C header) can

Tags: c++

see code below:

```cpp
#include <algorithm>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <cctype>
#include <string>

int main() {
    std::string str = "a String";
    
    // compile fail: template deduction fail for _Pred
    // return std::any_of(str.begin(), str.end(), std::isupper);

    // OK:
    return std::any_of(str.begin(), str.end(), isupper); // or ::isupper
}
```

both `std::isupper` and `isupper` have same declaration according to [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isupper):

> Defined in header < cctype>
>
> int isupper( int ch );

> Defined in header <ctype.h>
>
> int isupper( int ch );

So, why?

Comment: Side note: You don't want to call `isupper` or `std::isupper` raw unless you can be guaranteed `char` is unsigned. Details here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isupper#Notes

Comment: It compiles fine for me with the latest Clang and MSVC, but my (older) TDM barfs on it, complaining that it cannot resolve the _overloaded_ `isupper()`. However, don’t do that anyway, as **user4581301** notes. `std::any_of(..., []( unsigned char c ) { return isupper( c ); } )`

Comment: `<locale>` *also* has a *template* function named [`std::isupper`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/isupper), which makes it impossible for the compiler to deduce the type of `CharT` when you pass in `std::isupper`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's more than one `isupper` function is namespace `std`. One is `int std::isupper(int)` defined in <cctype>, and the other is `template <typename charT> bool isupper( charT ch, const locale& loc )` defined in <locale>.

It seems that your <cctype> also includes <locale>, and make the compiler cannot deduce which `isupper` is used. You can try the following:

```
return std::any_of(str.begin(), str.end(), static_cast<int (*)(int)>(std::isupper));
```

However, as others mentioned, you'd better use a lambda to wrap the call to `std::isupper`:

```
return std::any_of(str.begin(), str.end(), [](unsigned char c) { return std::isupper(c); });
```

Comment: Note, unless explicitly allowed, you should not take the address of a function from the standard library: [Can I take the address of a function defined in standard library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55687044/can-i-take-the-address-of-a-function-defined-in-standard-library)