# Can Niebloids be passed where Callables is required?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++20, niebloid

Generally speaking, unless explicitly allowed, the behavior of a C++ program that tries to take the pointer of a standard library function is unspecified. Which means extra caution should be taken before passing them as *[Callable](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Callable)*. Instead it is typically better to wrap them in a lambda.

<sup>More on the topic: [Can I take the address of a function defined in standard library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55687044/can-i-take-the-address-of-a-function-defined-in-standard-library)</sup>

---

However, C++20 introduced [Constrained algorithms](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/ranges), or ranged algorithms, based on the [Range-v3 library](https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3); where function-like entities, such as `std::ranges::sort` and `std::ranges::transform`, are introduced as Niebloids.

While the original library has created a functor class for each functions in the algorithm library, and each niebloids, such as `ranges::sort`, is simply a named object of the corresponding functor class; the standard does not specify how they should be implemented.

---

So the question is if the behavior of passing a Niebloid as a *Callable*, such as `std::invoke(std::ranges::sort, my_vec)`, specified/explicitly allowed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All the spec says, in [[algorithms.requirements]](https://eel.is/c++draft/algorithms#requirements-2) is:

> The entities defined in the `std​::​ranges` namespace in this Clause are not found by argument-dependent name lookup ([basic.lookup.argdep]). When found by unqualified ([basic.lookup.unqual]) name lookup for the postfix-expression in a function call ([expr.call]), they inhibit argument-dependent name lookup.

The only way to implement that, today, is by making them objects. However, we don't specify any further behavior of those objects.

So this:

```cpp
std::invoke(std::ranges::sort, my_vec)
```

will work, simply because that will simply evaluate as `std::ranges::sort(my_vec)` after taking a reference to it, and there's no way to really prevent that from working.

But other uses might not. For instance, `std::views::transform(r, std::ranges::distance)` is not specified to work, because we don't say whether `std::ranges::distance` is copyable or not - `std::ranges::size` is a customization point object, and thus copyable, but `std::ranges::distance` is just an algorithm.

The MSVC implementation tries to adhere aggressively to the limited specification, and its implementation of `std::ranges::distance` is *not* copyable. libstdc++, on the other hand, just makes them empty objects, so `views::transform(ranges::distance)` just works by way of being not actively rejected.

All of which to say is: once you get away from directly writing `std::ranges::meow(r)` (or otherwise writing `meow(r)` after a `using` or `using namespace`), you're kind of on your own.

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer! I just want to make sure, *'So this: [...] will work, simply because [...] there's no way to really prevent that from working'*. Is that based on the presumption that *'The only way to implement that, today, is by making them objects'*? While I don't think any particular implementation is doing that, it is mentioned on cppreference that it might be implemented with special compiler extensions.

Comment: @Ranoiaetep Sure, I suppose if somebody's going to go implement a dedicated language feature to implement `std::ranges::` algorithms, that dedicated language feature can do... whatever is they want it to do, so hypothetically it could also reject the `std::invoke(meow, r)` usage. But, short of that, no within-standard-C++23 implementation can reject such a thing.