# Is there a way to address more than one pair of elements in comparison predicate?

Tags: c++, stl, std, std-ranges

In the code below the `values` vector contains data indexed by `indexes`.

**Background**

It works just fine for sorting or searching while I have to deal with one value (actually, pair of them, lhs and rhs) in the comparator at a time. The problem comes when I want to use *a sequence of array elements* while sorting the indexes; they must be sorted not by the values, but by sequences of values.

**Question**

Is there an `std::range`-based solution which would allow me to address the sequences of the elements in the array in `std::range::sort` and in `std::range::equal_range`?

**Code**

Here is current implementation (not working with std::range::equal_range, but working with std::range::sort) with a ChainComparator which shows what exactly I want to have.

```cpp
auto make_index_projection = []<std::ranges::random_access_range R>(R & range) {
    return [&range](std::ranges::range_difference_t<R> i) -> decltype(auto) {
        return std::ranges::begin(range)[i];
        };
};

class ChainComparator {
    const std::vector<int>& vec;
public: 
    ChainComparator(const auto& vec) : vec(vec) {}

    bool operator() (int& lhs, int& rhs) {
        // Dirty trick
        auto lhs_range_begin = vec.begin() + (&lhs - std::data(vec));
        auto rhs_range_begin = vec.begin() + (&rhs - std::data(vec));

        return std::lexicographical_compare(lhs_range_begin, vec.end(), rhs_range_begin, vec.end());
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> values = { 0,30,20,40,10 };
    std::vector<int> indexes = { 3,4,2,1,0 };

    auto index_projection = make_index_projection(values);

    std::ranges::sort(indexes, ChainComparator(values), index_projection);

    auto indexing_view = indexes | std::views::transform(index_projection);

    std::vector<int> values_to_search = { 20, 40 };
    // Of course, doesn’t work since the dirty trick above requires all the arguments of comparison to be in the values array which is violated here
    auto range_pred_seq = std::ranges::equal_range(indexing_view, values_to_search, ChainComparator(values));
}
```

Comment: It is not clear what you're trying to do. Forget the indexes for the moment, what does it even mean to compare a single value to subsequences? Which subsequences? Also, `equal_range` requires the range being search to be at least partially ordered with respect to the search value and predicate.

Comment: Additionally, your predicate, as written, exhibits UB. Since `equal_range` is going to pass the search value itself as one of the predicate arguments, you can't subtract its address from the start of the vector, because they're not part of the same contiguous array.

Comment: I have to say the question is not clear as written and I think I am able to comprehend it only because I have followed your two previous questions. I hope my answer solves the real problem you are aiming at and demonstrates the power of ranges, projections and views used correctly.

Comment: @Kyle, well, let me answer item by item and sorry for not clear question (which confirmed by Weijun Zhou who already follows the chain of my questions), I will do my best to update.
(1) Let's consider one value as a sequence with one element. I understand the difference between their types (container of values and value), here I just stressed that I need both syntax cases (search for one value and search for a sequence of values) work. So, single value is *found*, not equal if it is the first value of the sequence. Note, I just look for a range. Like "if starts with this value".

Comment: @Kyle, (2) the range is ordered which is done by `std::ranges::sort` in 4th line of the main function. (3) On the "because they're not part of the same continuous array", I said about this in the initial question ("Dirty and risky workarounds" section, item #1) and noted the possible dirty trick ("Dirty and risky workarounds" section, item #2). Sorry again, if the wording is confusing.

Comment: @Kyle, could you please review the updated question. Does it address all your questions? If not, please help to improve further by your questions; if so, please consider removing/updating your comments to keep them up to date with the new question wording. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course what you are looking for is possible. After all, ranges are really powerful and flexible and cool :)

`make_index_projection` right now returns a single lvalue from the range, but you can also return a subrange, which is a view from the specified element to anywhere you are interested. In your example code, it seems that what you are interested are the subrange from the given element to the end, so let's do the same. For better demo, I am using a `std::string` (a range of `char`s instead  of a range of `int`s) because it is easier to print a `string`.

The range version of the `make_index_projection` is just as simple as follows,

```
auto make_index_projection_for_subrange = []<std::ranges::random_access_range R>(R & range) {
    return [&range](std::ranges::range_difference_t<R> i) -> decltype(auto) {
        return std::ranges::subrange(std::ranges::begin(range)+i, std::ranges::end(range));
        };
};
```

`std::ranges::subrange` is just the view you are looking for that keeps track of the underlying range with the custom indices you provide.

Now, you have already known that, to use projections and views to sort a range, you can do the following

```
    const std::string s1 = "abdbc";
    std::vector i1{0,1,2,3,4};
    
    //Sort by single char
    auto proj1 = make_index_projection(s1);
    std::ranges::sort(i1, {}, proj1);
```

Then, when you want to loop over the range indirectly via the indices, you make a view from the projection:

```
    auto view1 = i1 | std::views::transform(proj1);
```

If you then construct a `std::string` from the view, and then print it, you get the sorted result "abbcd". Not surprising.

```
    std::cout << std::string(view1.begin(), view1.end()) << std::endl;
```

(Hope now you can see why I chose a std::string to demo instead. Because it provides a very natural way to output the view, but this is just marginal).

I assume all stated above are what you already know about. Now let's try to use the new `make_index_projection_for_subrange` function. First, let's reset our indices to {0,1,2,3,4} so that we can better demonstrate what the view does.

```
    auto proj2 = make_index_projection_for_subrange(s1);
    std::ranges::sort(i1);
    auto view2 = i1 | std::views::transform(proj2);
```

Now let's examine the view,

```
    for(auto s: view2){
        std::cout << std::string(s.begin(), s.end()) << std::endl;
    }
```

The output

```
abdbc
bdbc
dbc
bc
c
```

This shows that each element of the view is itself a range (actually, a `subrange` view) that contains the substring from the current char  to the end of the string. This is exactly what you want to achieve in `ChainedComparator`, but in a much cleaner way.

Now it should be obvious how to sort the indices. Of course you still have to provide a custom comparator because comparison between two ranges is not well defined.

```
    std::ranges::sort(i1, [](auto&&... args){return std::ranges::lexicographical_compare(args...);}, proj2);
```

I digress a bit here. Originally, the code was just that

```
    std::ranges::sort(i1, std::ranges::lexicographical_compare, proj2);
```

This works in GCC and Clang, but not in current version of MSVC as pointed out by OP in a comment. This is because `std::ranges::lexicographical_compare` is a niebloid and using a niebloid as a callable is not always well defined per [this excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75227156/3966456). So far all major compiler vendors use objects to implement nieboids, but MSVC currently makes the object non-copyable<sup>1</sup>, so this simpler version does not work. It can be fixed by just adding a `std::cref` around it to avoid copying,

```
    std::ranges::sort(i1, std::cref(std::ranges::lexicographical_compare), proj2);
```

However, this is still not strictly standard-conforming, because a niebloid does not have to be an object at all and can be implemented via compiler magic. The real standard conforming way is using a lambda like above. Note that I have not included perfect forwarding in the lambda because I know that no sane implementation of  `lexicographical_compare` would attempt to copy the ranges, but in general perfect forwarding should be a concern, and the identity lambda should instead be

```
[]<typename... Ts>(Ts&&... args){
    return niebloid_to_be_forwarded(std::forward<Ts>(args)...);
}
```

Back to the main topic. Let's confirm our indices are indeed sorted as expected:

```
    view2 = i1 | std::views::transform(proj2);
    for(auto s: view2){
        std::cout << std::string(s.begin(), s.end()) << std::endl;
    }
```

Output:

```
abdbc
bc
bdbc
c
dbc
```

Isn't that cool? As I said, ranges are cool.
Now I see you are concerned about using `equal_range` to find a subsequence. That is of course no problem, either,

```
    auto eqn_range = std::ranges::equal_range(view2, std::string_view{"bdbc"}, [](auto&&... args){return std::ranges::lexicographical_compare(args...);});
```

The elements of `view2` are `subrange` views instead of `std::string_view`s, but `std::ranges::lexicographical_compare` is completely capable of comparing them. This just again shows how cool ranges are. Note that you cannot use `"bdbc"` itself here because it is a `const char[5]` and the final null byte will ruin your day.

Finally, we can confirm that the `equal_range` does give the expected result:

```
    std::cout << "eqn_range size: " << eqn_range.size() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "eqn_range begin: " << std::string_view((*eqn_range.begin()).begin(), (*eqn_range.begin()).end()) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "eqn_range end: " << std::string_view((*(eqn_range.end())).begin(), (*(eqn_range.end())).end()) << std::endl;
```

The outputs are:

```
eqn_range size: 1
eqn_range begin: bdbc
eqn_range end: c
```

Which confirms that `equal_range` has successfully found the sequence.

The complete demo can be found here: https://godbolt.org/z/cqrvanzPh

Finally, note that `s1` is `const std::string`, so all these sorting happen without modifying the value range. All that happens are index reordering.

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> According to [this bug report](https://github.com/microsoft/STL/pull/4098), MSVC has also decided to make the niebloid a CPO in the near future, so the simpler syntax will work for all three compilers. Thanks to @康桓瑋
for pointing out this in a comment.</sub>

Comment: I can't thank you enough for so comprehensive and precise answer. This is exactly what I am looking for and you hit the spot with the output of the sorted lines. I will share about the overall goal I pursue in the chat. Two kind requests, (1) I stuck with the compilation error for this code in Visual Studio 2022 . Could you please take a look at the [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/3Gz8KWdcz)? (2) If I need to have my own (more sophisticated) comparator, what is the syntax of this function object?

Comment: For the first one, just use a lambda. That is, use `[](auto&& v1, auto&& v2){return std::lexicographical_compare(v1, v2);}` in place of `std::lexicographical_compare` in my answer. I also believe this is a bug in MSVC. For the second one, I can't really answer without seeing the actual code, but just ask yourself this, what do you want the index (a single number) to represent. A single number cannot carry too much information. In this case it's just the subrange from itself to the end. If you have a well defined mapping from index to the underlying meaning of that index, ...

Comment: ... you can always express the mapping in terms of a view and put it into the function object. In C++20 the view you are looking for may be missing. I for example implemented a `chunk_view` my self. In C++23 the set of views should contain enough tools for you to express any mapping from an index to what you want the index to mean. If that is not a simple mapping, i.e. what you want the index to mean depends on contexts other than the index and the range themselves, the extra context can be passed as an additional argument to `make_index_projection`, ...

Comment: and the context will be captured by the lambda. So something like `auto make_index_projection_for_subrange = []<...>(R& range, Context& context){return [&range, &context](... i) -> decltype(auto){return some_view_object(range, i, context);}}` should be able to achieve any type of goal similar to this. Think twice before you decide that the `context` is needed, because in most cases, you can do without it.

Comment: After reading https://stackoverflow.com/a/75227156/3966456 I now believe MSVC is correct and you cannot just put a niebloid there. I will fix my answer later. Also see the chat for my intermediate thoughts.

Comment: If you only care about making it work in mainstream compilers and not really about being *pedantically* standard-conforming. [This](https://godbolt.org/z/4fh48W64n) is the minimal modification to make it work.

Comment: But MSVC [recently decided to change niebloid to CPO](https://github.com/microsoft/STL/pull/4098), so you can do that. (The three compilers have now implemented niebloid as copyable CPO).

Comment: @康桓瑋 Is it true that if I want to be strictly standard-conforming I still need to use a lambda, or am I just being too pedantic?