# Intuition behind the reverse iterator addressing adjustment

Tags: c++, stl

Trying to develop an intuition with addressing vector elements with indexes through forward and backward iterators. Since, for example per [en.cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/reverse_iterator),

> “For a reverse iterator r constructed from an iterator i, the relationship &*r == &*(i - 1) is always true”

is it obvious that in order to keep `it_backward` pointing to the same element as `it_backward` I have to compensate this with, subtracting one from the resulting backward iterator:

```cpp
    std::vector i1{ 0,1,2,3,4 };
    const int element_offset=3;
    auto it_forward = i1.begin()+element_offset;
    auto it_backward = std::make_reverse_iterator(it_forward)-1;

    std::cout << std::endl << "*(it_forward) = " << *(it_forward);
    std::cout << std::endl << "*(it_backward) = "  << *(it_backward);
```

to be more precise it would be better to use:

```cpp
    auto it_backward = std::prev(std::make_reverse_iterator(it_forward));
```

At the same time when we just reverse the range, this is done transparently for programmer and we don’t need to adjust the iterators and I see why.

```cpp
    std::copy(std::make_reverse_iterator(i1.end()),
              std::make_reverse_iterator(i1.begin()),
              std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, ", "));
```

My questions is, since these ways of addressing (ranges, elements, ranges limited by elements) sometimes used together, what is the best way to develop an intuition, when we have to adjust the backward iterator and when we don’t?

I can do this every time double checking myself and code, but maybe there is some kind of a good rule of thumb which could help to see when to adjust and when not to?

Comment: Why do you need this specific functionality? Can you give a sample code on intended use-case please?

Comment: the intutiion is to get expected semantics for `rend` and `rbegin`. Usually you dont need to adjust anything, it can be considered an imlementation detail hidden behind the `base` method. Why do you think you need to do that manually?

Comment: "is it obvious that I have to compensate this with..." no, sorry, not obvious

Comment: @Red.Wave, Indexing of array for reverse sequences (like text). Just see the [Is there a way to address more than one pair of elements in comparison predicate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77511005/is-there-a-way-to-address-more-than-one-pair-of-elements-in-comparison-predicate) and imagine providing the predicate which will do the same lexicographical comparison in backward direction. The predicate will get an index to the data array and will have to adjust before calling the lexicographical comparison.

Comment: @Red.Wave, another example would be usage structures of arrays (SoA) when I get the iterator in one array (for example with `std::lower_bound`), recalculate it to index, common for all arrays and do something backward-style with all arrays.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai, I am absolutely with it and I never ask why such a shift is made, I see how this works for (r)begin/r(end) and the elements after last. I don't understand your question "Why do you think you need to do that manually?"; I showed in my question that in order to point to the same element, I have to adjust. Although, its seems to me that I got your idea. Are you asking like "are you sure that after getting the reverse iterator you still need the same element and not the next one as the conversion does?" Is it your question?

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai, on the "no, sorry, not obvious" I meant that it is obvious in case you want the iterator to point at the same element. Sorry for confusion, I will update the question. Again, it seems to me that I got your answer, maybe it most cases not exactly this element, but the next one will be necessary. Nevertheless, consider my examples in my answer to Red above.

Comment: I still can't see were you need to go with this. Show an example code snippet for your intended use-case please. Code speaks better.

Comment: @Red.Wave. Please see the [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/jo9b5W7cf).

Comment: @DamirTenishev It seems like your indices are off-by-one in that example: The empty sequence is given by `-1` instead of `0`

Comment: @Artyer, I can't understand your comment. The result is "as expected". What do you mean with "empty sequence"?  What do you mean by "-1"? Can you please show with the updated code? Well, I might not introduced some corner case checks (still not sure they are necessary), but the request from Red.Wave was to show the idea in the code, not all the checks.

Comment: `vec | take(n+1) | reverse` for reverse and `vec | drop(n)` for forward. Then just `auto rng=zip(idx, vec);` next `ranges::sort(rng, ranges::lexicographical_compare, [&vec](auto& p){auto&[_, n]=p; return /*above*/;});`. By `using namespace std::views;`, all that compiles fine. No need to manipulate iterators.

Comment: @Red.Wave, thank you so much. Although this evades from the original question, it helps to avoid the question at all. The only problem is that I can't zip projections and if I zip views, sort doesn't compile. Could you please take a look at the [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/hcodcexfq)? Have I missed something? Should I create a new question for this specifics?

Comment: `zip` is C++23. `range-v3` version should work with C++20 or below. The question actually didn't really center about revesring ranges though: as you can see, it was about skipping N elements or keeping N+1.

Comment: `std::views` is a short-hand for `std::ranges::views`.

Comment: @DamirTenishev It seems like your "indices" are identifying prefixes of the array. It would seem more natural for the number to correspond to the size of the prefix (or the endpoint being exclusive). It also gets rid of the +1: https://godbolt.org/z/Pa9GcvoT9

Comment: @Red.Wave, the [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/hcodcexfq) I published in the comment above is clang with c++ 23, so I assume it is C++23. I use std::ranges::views::zip and the code in demo still doesn't compile. I can't make head nor tail why it doesn't compile. I like your approach for solving this task much more than mine, but I can't get it working. Could you please help to realize what is the cause of the issue?

Comment: @Artyer, thank you this helps. One thing is still my concern which is your index 6. What do you mean with it? It references to end of values array (one element past last). We still can refer to end, but what is the value to refer to object which we can't deference? In which way it gives you the empty sequence? Just because it is the only option to get the empty sequence here by index referencing?

Comment: As I mentioned earlier, `range-v3` is the replica(actually prototype) for `<ranges>`. If neither one is working, then you can still fall back to old iterator version; you have a more compact and more descriptive implementation of your projections. `take` and `drop` are C++20.

Comment: There's a typo in the demo: either `auto& [n, _]` or `zip(values, indexes)`. Because `n` is supposed to iterate over `indexes`, and it has to be placed at same positional order.

Comment: @Red.Wave, I don't thank swapping values and indexes will affect the compilation perspective, since to compiler both are arrays; the results will change, of course. Anyway, I tried both auto& [n, _]  [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/n5Y878v81) and zip(values, indexes) [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/Th34a9xqr). Nothing helps

Comment: I noticed that the compiler is set to C++20. You need to specify that option yourself. Compiler explorer may default to wrong value.

Comment: I double checked this in my demos and creating a new demo with the explicit `-std=c++23` in the compiler options. I double checked this with the recent Visual Studio 2022 with `/std:c++latest` option. Nothing helps. std::ranges::sort doesn't accept std::ranges::zip_view.

Comment: Structured binding strikes again. Change `auto& [_,n]` to `auto [_,n]`. Amd `auto& p` to `auto p`.

Comment: That question also mentions a problem, I was lazy to mention. Your algorithm is eventually changing comparator, which is not standard behavior anyway.

Comment: @Artyer, you are right about the "It seems like your "indices" are identifying prefixes of the array". I am familiar with it as "array of reminders" when I have an index to the reminder of the sequence. For prefixes of array I familiar only with sum prefixes although I understand that this could be any valid convolutional operation. Can you please give a reference to any source which consider array such mine as "prefixes of the array"? Just want to catch up here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pairs of iterators denote half-open ranges. The first iterator is dereferenceable until it is equal to the second.

If you required passing an iterator to the element you desired to `std::reverse_iterator`, then you couldn't use `end` for the start, nor could you use the `begin` of an empty range. Also there is no iterator value that corresponds to the past-the-end of the reversed range.

What you should avoid thinking about is constructing a `reverse_iterator` to a particular element, and instead construct *pairs* of reverse iterators that denote the *range* of elements you want, having swapped the begin and end. I.e. instead of your example

```
auto it_forward = i1.begin()+element_offset;
auto it_backward = std::make_reverse_iterator(it_forward)-1;
```

You would have

```
auto it_forward_begin = i1.begin()+element_offset;
auto it_forward_end = i1.begin()+element_offset+1;
auto it_backward_begin = std::make_reverse_iterator(it_forward_end);
auto it_backward_end = std::make_reverse_iterator(it_forward_begin);
```

Now you can simplify that, inlining the end iterator

```
auto it_backward = std::make_reverse_iterator(it_forward+1);
```

or

```
auto it_backward = std::make_reverse_iterator(std::next(it_forward));
```

Comment: Thank you. In helps, but I still have some questions. (1) Despite the brilliant point to focus on ranges rather than elements and that it co-sounds with what @463035818_is_not_an_ai says in comments above, this still doesn't give me the intuition, it gives (me) just a better understanding. (2) Could you please consider my examples I provided in the answer to Red.Wave under my question, is there still a chance to think in ranges rather than in positions in these cases?

Comment: @DamirTenishev if you have C++20 or range-v3, rather than doing the projection in the comparator with indexes, you can supply a projection to the algorithm, e.g. [here](https://godbolt.org/z/nv95zsarx)