# Sorting with zipped views

Tags: c++, std-ranges

Is there any chance to get this code working?

The problem as I see it, is that `std::ranges::sort` doesn’t work with `std::ranges::zip_view` and there is no way to pass this view to sort. The line with `std::ranges::sort` come with tons of error messages which I don't want to copy here.

The program sorts array by backward prefixes.

The thing in the code below I want to keep is its pipeline approach in projection predicate to handle sequences. If there is any other working idea which will allow to keep the pipeline approach, it is all hands welcome as soon as it doesn't create copies of values and indexes.

```cpp
#include <execution>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <ranges>

int main()
{
    std::vector values={7,3,9,2,4,7};
    std::vector indexes={0,1,2,3,4,5};

    auto rng=std::ranges::views::zip(indexes, values);

    std::ranges::sort(rng, std::ranges::lexicographical_compare, 
      [&values](auto& p){auto&[n, _]=p; return values | std::ranges::views::take(n+1) | std::ranges::views::reverse;});


    for (auto i : indexes) {
        for (int vi = 0; vi < i; ++vi) {
           std::cout << values[vi] << " ";
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/6K7WxqhKa)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`zip_view`'s `reference_type` is `std::tuple<int&, int&>`, which is what dereferencing its iterators returns.

This is a prvalue and can't bind to your function argument `p` in your projection `[&values](auto& p){ ... }`.

Simply change it to `(auto p)` or `(auto&& p)` and this should compile.

However, it is now incorrect because swapping two elements of the zip view will change elements in `values` as well as in `indexes`. Since this also changes the meaning of the comparator, it makes the comparator invalid.

You probably want to only sort `indexes`, which you can do by projecting each of the indices into a reversed prefix:

```cpp
std::ranges::sort(indexes, std::ranges::lexicographical_compare, [&values](int i) {
    return values | std::ranges::views::take(i+1) | std::ranges::views::reverse;
});
```

(If you really do mean to sort both at the same time, you need to take a copy of `values` so it doesn't change during the sort)

Comment: Thank you so much. Changing to (auto p) or (auto&& p) doesn't help and the code doesn't compile, but since it will lead to wrong results, let's keep it aside. With you last suggestion code works, but the outcome [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/a96nTMd3h) is not what I expect [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/43b5vrqqb). It is very hard to debug this code, so I on my way to understand what leads to this difference. If you can catch, please share.

Comment: I slightly reworked the code extracting comp and proj to make it easier to debug and came to the following [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/W3x3GoMbj) which runs without problems in VS2022, but the results are still not what I expect and when I debug the input for comp lambda, it always shows for both arguments full values array without any reverse; maybe this is how views debugging works due to their lazy evaluation nature. The same code doesn't compile on godbolt.org with clang and crashes godbold compilation with msvc. I will create a new question on this tomorrow.

Comment: @DamirTenishev Apply the projection on the output again. That lambda doesn't need to be template; a mere  `[](auto& r)` is simpler.

Comment: @DamirTenishev `views::take(i+1)` should be `views::take(i)`, and your index array should be `{0,1,2,3,4,5,6}` instead of `{0,1,2, 3,4,5}`. [So it should work as you expect.](https://godbolt.org/z/q53on9dbh).

Comment: @Red.Wave, sorry, it seems that I again missed something. (1) Where in this post the lambda is a template? It was the `[](auto&)` from the beginning here. Have I missed something? (2) Why should I apply the projection on the output **again**? The code below from 康桓瑋 works as expected without additional projection application. Am I wrong?

Comment: @康桓瑋, thank you so much! This +1 came from my [previous code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77531663/intuition-behind-the-reverse-iterator-addressing-adjustment) where I tried to create a reverse iterator and I forgot it. You made my day.

Comment: Just out of curiosity (when the task is solved), I wasn't able to get the original code compiled both with change to `(auto p)' not '(auto&& p)'. Keeping it aside to get this working, just to better understand prvalues and bindings, all things considered, should `(const auto& p)` work or not?

Comment: @康桓瑋, I have to take it back. The +1 is vital for correct code work in real environment. Please see the [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/M4GaEcEe3). The key problem is that without this +1 the indexes will point to wrong positions (projection will be one position off) because `views::take(i)` takes first `i` elements which is wrong for this case, since `i` elements contains set of elements [0,i) and `i` positioned element of the sequence is missing in projections which is easy to see with debugging output in my demo. Please, let me know if I am wrong.