# Overloaded Function as Argument to Templated Function

Tags: c++, clang, clang++, c++-templates

I have stumbled upon an issue with templates in `clang++` that I do not know how to solve.

I wish to use templated functions that take a class and a function as arguments. But when the function is an overloaded function, I get the error `candidate template ignored: couldn't infer template argument 'F'` which is totally sensible.

For instance, the example program

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>

template<class T, typename F>
T foo(F f,T x){
  return f(x);
}

int main(void) {
  std::cout << "foo(sinf,0.34) is " << foo(sinf,0.34) << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

works exactly as I want. Now, if I use an overloaded function such as `sin` instead of `sinf`, the template argument cannot be inferred. How can I change the function template of `foo` to help the compiler resolving the type of `F`?

Comment: Oh no, I think I accidentally deleted the comments. I am very sorry!

Comment: Your program has unspecified behaviour because `sinf` is not an addresable function, [see](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55687044/can-i-take-the-address-of-a-function-defined-in-standard-library). You need to wrap it in your own function or lambda. So might just as well wrap `sin`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a lambda to solve the ambiguity with overloads, eg:

```
foo([](double d){ return sin(d); }, 0.34)
```

---

On a side note, in C++, you should use `<cmath>` instead of `<math.h>` directly.  You can use `using namespace std;` or better `using std::sin;` to bring `std::sin` into the calling namespace if you don't want to qualify it at the call site.

Comment: I tried using `cmath` and and adding the standard namespace, but that did not help. But the lambda function does the job. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: @AntonRydahl `<math.h>` defines only 1 `sin()` function, in the global namespace. `<cmath>` defines overloaded `sin()` functions, in the `std` namespace.

Comment: `cmath` is allowed to define the global function, and `math.h` is allowed to define the one in `std`.

Comment: Ideally you would always `#include <cmath>` and use `std::sin`, anything beyond that is relying on features that aren't guaranteed in C++.

Comment: Just to be clear: `<math.h>` definitely declares `::sin` and may declare `std::sin`. `<cmath>` definitely declares `std::sin` and may declare `::sin`.

Answer (score 5):

There are multiple ways to resolve this. First of all, you could convert to the appropriate function pointer type:

```cpp
foo(static_cast<double(*)(double)>(sin));
```

However, this is **unspecified behavior (possibly ill-formed)**, because `sin` is not an [addressable function](http://eel.is/c++draft/namespace.std#def:function,addressable).
It's perfectly fine to do this for your own functions, just not for functions in the standard library.

To be safe, you can wrap this function in a lambda expression:

```cpp
foo([](double x) { return sin(x); }, 0.34);
```

#### Note on "lifting" functions frequently

It happens quite often that you have to "lift" standard library functions like this, so some people define a macro:

```cpp
// TODO: perfect forwarding, conditional noexcept, ...
#define LIFT(...) [](auto &&...args) { return __VA_ARGS__(args...); }

foo(LIFT(sin), 0.34);
```

#### Note on reducing instantiations

`[](double x) { return sin(x); }` denotes a unique *closure type*, so we are calling `foo<CLOSURE, double>`. We might still want to call `foo<double(*)(double), double>` instead, to save on instatiations.

The *closure type* defined by a lambda expression is implicitly convertible to a function pointer if the lambda expression has no captures.
You could explicitly cast to a `double(*)(double)`, or pass `+[](double x) ...` if you wanted to call `foo` with a function pointer instead of the lambda expression.

#### Note on perfect forwarding

Your original `foo` could be improved as follows:

```cpp
template<class T, class F>
T foo(F &&f, T &&x){
  return std::forward<F>(f)(std::forward<T>(x));
}
```

- forwarding `x` means that we possibly use the move constructor when calling `f`
- forwarding `f` means that we possibly use an rvalue-ref-qualified call operator (it's rare that this exists, but it theoretically can)

Comment: Thank you so much for the quick reply! This works as I hoped it would. :D

Comment: Your macro needs `-> decltype(...)` return type for SFINAE friendliness, and also `noexcept` for bonus points. And perfect forwarding.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I've put this into the `TODO`, didn't want it to look like the monstrosity that a `LIFT` macro normally is :)