# Pass `std::optional::value` to `std::views::transform`

Tags: c++, c++20, std-ranges, stdoptional

I cannot seem to pass `std::optional::value` to `std::views::transform`.
However, I can pass `std::optional::has_value` without any issues:

```
#include <optional>
#include <ranges>
#include <vector>

int main () {

    std::vector<std::optional<int>> myVec{{1,2,3}};

    const auto result = myVec
        | std::views::filter(&std::optional<int>::has_value)
        | std::views::transform(&std::optional<int>::value);

    return 0; 
}
```

As an example, here is the error I get with x86-64 clang 16.0.0 and passing the `-std=c++20` flag:

```
<source>:15:11: error: no matching function for call to object of type 'const _Transform'
        | std::views::transform(&std::optional<int>::value);
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-12.2.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/12.2.0/../../../../include/c++/12.2.0/ranges:891:2: note: candidate template ignored: substitution failure: deduced incomplete pack <(no value)> for template parameter '_Args'
        operator()(_Args&&... __args) const
        ^
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-12.2.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/12.2.0/../../../../include/c++/12.2.0/ranges:2057:2: note: candidate function template not viable: requires 2 arguments, but 1 was provided
        operator() [[nodiscard]] (_Range&& __r, _Fp&& __f) const
        ^
1 error generated.
Compiler returned: 1
```

Do you know what is going on?

Natually, as a workaround, I can use a lambda, though that doesn't feel nearly as satisfactory:

```
const auto thisWorks = myVec
  | std::views::filter(&std::optional<int>::has_value)
  | std::views::transform([] (const auto& opt) {return opt.value();});
```

Comment: The C++ standard library has the notion of "addressable" functions. Meaning those functions whose address a program may legally take. Those members are not designated as addressable, so there's no guarantees. It's a lambda or nothing (for both members) is promised.

Comment: For bigger/non copiable types, lambda should return reference (with trailing returned type) and not by value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem becomes very clear when compiling with GCC, which yields the error:

```
error: no match for call to '(const std::ranges::views::_Transform) (<unresolved overloaded function type>)'
   15 |         | std::views::transform(&std::optional<int>::value);
      |           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Pay special attention to *`<unresolved overloaded function type>`*.

`&std::optional<int>::value` takes the address of an unresolved overloaded function type because this member function has overloads for `const`, non-`const`, lvalue references, and rvalue references.
In total, [`std::optional::value`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional/value) has four overloads, and the compiler doesn't know which one to choose when you take its address.

You can suppress the error as follows:

```cpp
// This works because we are manually resolving the type through an implicit
// conversion, similar to how overload resolution works when calling functions.
int& (std::optional<int>::*value_fun)() & = &std::optional<int>::value;

const auto result = myVec
    | std::views::filter(&std::optional<int>::has_value)
    | std::views::transform(value_fun);
```

*See [live example at Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/WcE1xY7Tx)*.

However, while this *technically* compiles, it's not pretty, and `value` is not an *addressable function*.
This means that taking its address has unspecified effect, and the program might even be ill-formed. See also: [Can I take the address of a function defined in standard library?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55687044/5740428)

You should use your workaround with lambdas for both `filter` and `transform`. It is the idiomatic and correct solution, even if it isn't as concise.

Comment: With overload resolver, verbosity of lambda is comparable.